# Django+DRF FileUpload: How to get upload progress when uploading large files

Tags: django

I am trying to upload large files in Django (max size 2GB files)

currently I am trying

```
file = request.data['file1']
file_name = file.name
outFile = open(file_name, "wb+")
# check if the file size is less than 2.5mb else write in chunks
if not file.multiple_chunks():
    outFile.write(file.read())
else:
    for chunk in file.chunks(chunk_size=1000000):
        outFile.write(chunk)
outFile.close()
```

Now is there any way I can send the status of upload to the frontend.

I am ok to use another api call from server to check this.

Answer (score -1):

django is providing file upload with progress functionality [Modifying upload handlers on the fly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/file-uploads/#modifying-upload-handlers-on-the-fly)

Comment: Can you show an example

Comment: https://django.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/http/file-uploads.html

Comment: can you attach more code ?

Comment: The links are not the progress indicator.  They only describe how to use a progress indicator that you have already coded.